# Using VSCode to launch apps in GCP

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-code

not sure if this has been asked before though I couldn't find it. I am using GCP services such as app engine, secret manager and storage but am using the Cloud Shell editor. Though I like it, I prefer coding on VScode due to familiarity. Any help on how could I achieve this on my VS code terminal?

Answer (score 3):

@Sachin - We have support for all the features that are available in Cloud Shell in the local VSCode IDE through the cloud code plugin. Here is where you want to get started.

[Quick start & Install](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install)

[Plugin on VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode)